# How to set custom color in the view controller's background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background-color

I want to set the background color of my mobile app to #B2B27A.

I can get to View Controller and the Background color panel, but I cannot figure out how to set my own RGB color. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 178/255, green: 178/255, blue: 122/255, alpha: 1)
```

The `rgb` values are equal to `#B2B27A`.

**Edit:**
You can also add an hex/rgb value in your Storyboard:
[image]

1. Select your view
2. Click background in attributes inspector
3. Select the second menu item in the colors window

Comment: Ok, cool. Got it. Thanks @RashwanL. I was thinking the interface panel would give me the ability. I now see I know to go to the code level for colors outside the standards in the panel.

Comment: And where do I put that line of code @RashwanL? And if it goes in the *.storyboard file, how do I bring that file into view in Xcode-beta?

Comment: In your `viewDidLoad`for that viewController. You can also add in in your Storyboard check my update.

Comment: Thanks @RashwanL. It was the "sliders" panel set to RBG I was expecting to use...my panel was set to Grascale and I did not think to use the pullldown to change it to RGB.

Comment: Quick followup question @RashwanL. Is there anyway to set custom colors in the tool for say, my brand's color palette? (see [screen shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bytqhoir_Tt5ZEJPU0ktVHJ0cFE/view?usp=sharing))

Answer (score 2):

create a NSObject class as below:

```
class color:NSObject
{
    class func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
}
```

call this class func in you ViewController viewDidLoad() like below:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = color.UIColorFromRGB(0xB2B27A)
```